# Getting the last element of a PaginatedList in Python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

## How can I get the last element of a PaginatedList?#

(`<github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList object at 0x7f1c6a492a50>`).

My code is something like this -
`a_project_column.get_cards()[-1]` and the error is

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

But the below code is working fine for getting the desired result (i.e., > >ProjectCard(id=5161717))

`a_project_column.get_cards()[0]`

**For reference**
https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/PaginatedList.py

Comment: Looks like this is not an intended use. What happens when you try `yourlist._PaginatedList__elements[-1]`?

Comment: Yeah if you look at the embedded Slice class it doesn't have support for negative indexing.

Comment: @timgeb It shows error - AttributeError : 'PaginatedList' object has no attribute '_PaginatedList__elements'

Comment: @NoahSmithYeah Now it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needing to get the last of a PR's commits (returned as a PaginatedList), I got the following to do what I wanted:

```
pr.get_commits().reversed[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a while, but I found the solution to this and I figured I'd provide it for anyone who should go Googling as I did, to no avail:

Instead of

```
a_project_column.get_cards()[-1]
```

Try:

```
cards = a_project_column.get_cards()
final_card  = cards[cards.totalCount - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to get the last element of a list.
You can use list slicing : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

You're syntax is just a little off (you're missing the colon)

```
cards = a_project_column.get_cards()[-1:]
```